# generating PDF report in Java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to create a pdf report from database with 2 tables and the report is extracted from single row in sequence from the 2 tables. Like when row Id 1 is selected from table A then  go to table B and get information with same values then go to second raw from table A and select raw 2 and so on.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: I want to know how to do that

Comment: Look into the Jasper Reports library and Jaspersoft Studio.  Both are available at no cost.  You'll also need to learn how to make a connection to your database system through JDBC.